# Combinatorial equation correctness and name

Tags: combinatorics, reference-request, summation, terminology, binomial-coefficients

Is the following combinatorial equation correct? If yes, is it a well-known identity & does it have a specific name? I derived it from Pascal's identity. A reference would be helpful.
$$ {\binom{n}{k}} = \sum_{i=0}^m {\binom{m}{i}}{\binom{n-m}{k-i}} $$ where $0 \leq m \leq k$.

Thanks!

Comment: It is true if $k<m$ too as long as you define $\binom a b=0$ when $b<0,$ which is the usual definition.

Comment: Yes makes sense .. helped me connect to Vandermonde's identity better. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes! It is called [Vandermonde's identity.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity)

Comment: Yes indeed.. thanks so much :)